Problems when proving surjectivity.
I have some question when proving surjectivity of functions in some type of propositions such as this one from Terrence Tao Analysis book (Proposition 3.6.14, (c)):
Let $X$ be a finite set, and let $Y$ be a subset of $X$. Then $Y$ is finite, and $\#(Y ) ≤ \#(X)$.
I am ok with the strategy to prove such statements: We need to construct a bijection from a finite set to Y. Also, since $x$ is finite, there is a bijection $f:\{1,2,...,m\}\to X$ for some natural number $m$. Hence, we should be able to construct a bijection $g$ in terms of $f$.
I have tried two approaches when constructing $g$:

defining $g:\{1,2,...,n\}\to Y$ for some $n\leq m$ such that $g(i)=f(i)$ for all $i$ in the domain
defining $A=f^{-1}(Y)$ and $g:A\to Y$, such that $g(i)=f(i)$ for all $i\in A$ .

In both approaches, I mannaged to prove injectivity with no problems, but when it came to surjectivity, I was in trouble:

surjectivity of case 1:

We want to show that for every $y\in Y$, there is an $i\in \{ 1,2,\dots,n \}$ such that $y=g(i)$.
Let $a\in Y$ be arbitrary. Since $Y\subseteq X$, it follows that $a\in X$. Since $f$ is bijective, there is a unique $j\in \{ 1,2,\dots,m \}$ such that $a=f(j)$.
Now I am in trouble, since $j$ could be greater then $n$. I think I could never have picked a set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ in the first place, because then I am almost saying in advance that the cardinality of $Y$ is $n$, but I'm not sure of this.

In my second approach I started the proof like this:

Let $y\in Y$ be arbitrary. Since $Y\subseteq X$, $y\in X$.
Since $f$ is bijective, there is a unique $i\in \{ 1,2,\dots,m \}$ such that $y=f(i)$.
Since $y\in Y$, it follows that $f(i)\in Y$ and so $i\in f^{-1}(y),$ which implies $i\in A$. Thus $g(i)=f(i)=y$.
Thus, $g$ is surjective.
This approach seemed to work, but I don't know if I can assume that $f^{-1}(Y)$ is finite at this point. It seems to already depend on the fact that a subset of a finite set is finite, which is what I am trying to prove...
In summary my questions are:

What exactly is wrong with approach 1?
Is there a problem with assumption 2? Can I assume that $f^{-1}(Y)$ is a finite set as I did?
If none of the approaches work after some adjustments, I need a hint to proceed...


Since $Y$ is in $X$, one direction should be easy.  $f:Y \rightarrow X:y \rightarrow y$ (this is in the constellation of ideas "identified with itself").  In the reverse direction, the $Y$ part of $X$ can be identified with itself and all the other elements of $X$ can be dumped to any element of $Y$ that you like.  (This second step has a technicality if $Y$ is empty, so handle the $X$ is empty, $X$ is nonempty and $Y$ is empty cases before starting on the general proof.)

If $X$ is finite and $Y$ is a proper subset of $X$ then there is no bijection between them. You can show a surjection $X \to Y$ and an injection $Y \to X$ but you can't get a surjection $Y \to X$ or an injection $X \to Y$. Try this with $X = {1,2,3}$ and $Y={1,2}$ to build some intuition and then structure your proof using those ideas.
